# how to Import/Export Rhino's 3dm format to/from blender

Tags: add-on, import

How do I  Import/Export Rhino's 3dm format to/from blender 2.9 on Ubuntu system.  I tried https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/releases add-on. It works for my window system however on Ubuntu it says it has installed but I am unable to find it in add-on list to enable it. Am i missing something for Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS or this add-on doesn't work on ubuntu, is there any alternative? I am using  blender 2.9.
Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/jesterKing/import_3dm/issues/73

Comment: Thank you, Tried few things but no success yet.

Comment: Just wanted to add : I had installed rhino3dm.py and test program was also successfully executed, however rhino3dm.py is installed in my local python3.8. Could that be issue, does it need to installed in python3.7 in blender folder. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.